# I can't see my variable name in property expressions editor in foreach loop container

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis, etl, msbi

I am writing the SSIS package in Visual Studio. I have created a variable named 'Directory' but I can't see it in Property expressions Editor, See image for details. What is the issue here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The property drop down list shows the properties you need to evaluate as an expression, not the variables

The variables are visible and can be used within the Expression Editor *(while assigning an expression to a property)*

If you are looking to evaluate a variable as an expression, you can use an *Expression Task* or *Evaluate As an Expression* property:

- [SSIS Expression Tasks vs Evaluating variables as expressions](https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-expression-task-vs-evaluating-variable-as-expression/)

#### More details

Property Expressions in SSIS packages are assigned to a property at run time. This allows parameters to be passed to a package every time they are run.

You can add an expression to any read/write property in most of a package’s objects, which includes the package itself, the containers and tasks in the control flow, connection managers, event handlers, and log providers.

Inside the Expression Builder, you can use the variables.
The Expression window provides a workspace for creating your expressions. You can drag variables, functions, and operators from the two upper windows into the workspace.

The Evaluate Expression button launches the logic necessary to evaluate the expression in the Expression window.